# Seconds Counting in Milliseconds

Tags: c#, timer, clock, stopwatch

I've been coding a Stopwatch app in C#, but have encountered a problem. The Seconds seem to be counting in milliseconds.

Code:

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isActive) 
            {
                timeSSec++;

                if (timeSSec >=60)
                {
                    timeSMin = 1;
                    timeSSec = 0;
                }
            }
            DrawTime();
        }

        private void DrawTime()
        {
            SSec.Text = String.Format("{0:00}", timeSSec);
            SMin.Text = String.Format("{0:00}", timeSMin);
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Many thanks,
Ray

*I've fixed it now, I just added an invisible Millisecond role*

Comment: Who is calling `timer1_Tick`?

Comment: What is the Interval of timer1? And why do you maintain your own `isActive` flag when the timer has an `Enabled` property? `timeSMin = 1` should probably be `timeSMin += 1`. Please provide a [mre]. [edit] your question to include all necessary code

Comment: Instead of counting your own time (which will become inexact for longer periods), better remember the start time and calculate the delta.